# Tool with similar IFC processing capabilties as BIMServer

Tags: ifc, bim

I used BIMServer to create datamodels out of IFC elements.
Due to issues with it I need to switch the tool I process the IFC file with.
The big pro on BIMServer was that I did not need to know how the geometry is created and did not need to generate it myself. I was provided with vertices, indices and normals. The API provided me a way to recursively transform the vertices so that I get the absolute coordinate.

I am looking for a tool that has the same capabilities.
What are the alternatives?

Comment: You don't need an IFC tool. You need a CAD Software.

Comment: The requirement is to do it with IFC, since it is open

Comment: Many programs have an IFC export and import.

Comment: The question is not about IFC export or import, it is about  processing the data inside it

Answer (score 1):

BIMServer uses IFCOpenShell to generate the geometry - you could use that directly.

Other open source projects that can generate tesselated geometry from IFC are xBim and IfcPlusPlus.